How to create a plot in Matplotlib that looks like a swarmplot but with overlapping points?
I'm trying to create a (sort of) swarmplot - that it-  should clearly show the shapes of the distributions but allow for quick plotting of tens of thousands of datapoints by overlapping the dot representations of datapoints. Such as this:

My idea is to essentially create a dot plot but divide each distribution into quantiles and apply jitter to the horizontal positions of the datapoints whose magnitude is proportional to the number of points in the given quartile. This works fine when the distributions are of the same size but I need some way of scaling the jitter so that when one of the distributions has only a few datapoints the dots representing them would be arranged on a (nearly) vertical line i.e. NOT like below:

Here is my code for plot creation:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def fancy_distribution_plot(distributions: list, tick_labels: list, max_plot_width: int = 1, alpha=0.7,
                            number_of_segments=12,
                            separation_between_plots=0.1,
                            separation_between_subplots=0.1,
                            vertical_limits=None,
                            grid=False,
                            remove_outlier_above_segment=None,
                            remove_outlier_below_segment=None,
                            y_label=None,
                            title=None):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    number_of_plots = len(distributions)
    # print(f" number of plots {number_of_plots}")
    # print(f" max x line {number_of_plots * (max_plot_wwidth + separation_between_plots) + separation_between_plots}")

    ax.set_xlim(left=0, right=number_of_plots * (max_plot_width + separation_between_plots) + separation_between_plots)

    ticks = [separation_between_plots + max_plot_width / 2 + (max_plot_width + separation_between_plots) * i
             for i in range(0, number_of_plots)]
    print(ticks)

    for i in range(len(distributions)):
        distribution = distributions[i]
        # print(f"distribution {distribution}")
        segments = np.linspace(np.min(distribution), np.max(distribution), number_of_segments + 1)[1:-1]
        # print(f"segments {segments}")
        segment_indices = number_of_segments - 1 - np.where(segments[:, None] >= distribution[None, :], 1, 0).sum(0)
        # print(f"quantile indices {segment_indices}")
        if remove_outlier_above_segment:
            a = remove_outlier_above_segment[i]
            distribution = distribution[segment_indices <= a]
            segment_indices = segment_indices[segment_indices <= a]

        if remove_outlier_below_segment:
            b = remove_outlier_below_segment[i]
            distribution = distribution[segment_indices >= b - 1]
            segment_indices = segment_indices[segment_indices >= b - 1]

        values, counts = np.unique(segment_indices, return_counts=True)
        # print(f"values {values}")
        # print(f"counts {counts}")
        counts_filled = []
        j = 0
        for k in range(number_of_segments):
            if k in values:
                counts_filled.append(counts[j])
                j += 1
            else:
                counts_filled.append(0)
        variances = (max_plot_width / 2) * (counts_filled / np.max(counts))
        # print(f"variances {variances}")
        jitter_unadjusted = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, len(distribution))
        jitter = np.take(variances, segment_indices) * jitter_unadjusted
        # print(f"jitter {jitter}")
        ax.scatter(jitter + ticks[i], distribution, alpha=alpha)

    ax.set_xticks(ticks)
    ax.set_xticklabels(tick_labels)
    if vertical_limits:
        ax.set_ylim(bottom=vertical_limits[0], top=vertical_limits[1])
    if not grid:
        ax.grid(False)
    if y_label:
        ax.set_ylabel(y_label)
    if title:
        ax.set_title(title)
    plt.show()


And the code to recreate the second chart above:
# Create example random data
np.random.seed(0)
distro1 = np.random.normal(0, 2, 4)
distr2 = np.random.normal(1, 1, 10)
distr3 = np.random.normal(2, 3, 1000)

distributions = [distro1, distr2, distr3]
fancy_distribution_plot(distributions, tick_labels=['distro1', 'distro2', 'distro3'], number_of_segments=100,
                        grid=False)



Maybe seaborn's violinplot would be interesting here?

@JohanC Yes - definitely - that's one solution but I was wondering if I can make the shape of the distribution even more accurate.

How to make dots in Swarmplot overlap with each other suggests a hack temporarily changing the figsize to create overlapping dots. But that hack doesn't seem to work anymore in the latest (improved) matplotlib. An alternative is using smaller dots (sns.swarmplot(..., size=2).

My suggestion is to change this line variances = (max_plot_width / 2) * (counts_filled / np.max(counts)) to something like variances = (max_plot_width / 2) * (counts_filled / max_counts) where max_counts is the maximum counts for all the distributions, and not only the i-th one. To do so, you have to split your for loop into two parts, one to get the counts, and one to set the scaled jitter and actually plot.

Expanding on my comment, you could scale the variance (and thus the jitter) dividing by the max count amongst all of the distributions.
A possible implementation (starting from your function) is:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def fancy_distribution_plot(distributions: list, tick_labels: list, max_plot_width: int = 1, alpha=0.7,
                            number_of_segments=12,
                            separation_between_plots=0.1,
                            separation_between_subplots=0.1,
                            vertical_limits=None,
                            grid=False,
                            remove_outlier_above_segment=None,
                            remove_outlier_below_segment=None,
                            y_label=None,
                            title=None):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    number_of_plots = len(distributions)

    ax.set_xlim(left=0, right=number_of_plots * (max_plot_width + separation_between_plots) + separation_between_plots)

    ticks = [separation_between_plots + max_plot_width / 2 + (max_plot_width + separation_between_plots) * i
             for i in range(0, number_of_plots)]
    
    max_counts = 0.0
    counts_filled_list = []
    segment_indices_list = []
    for i in range(len(distributions)):
        distribution = distributions[i]
        
        segments = np.linspace(np.min(distribution), np.max(distribution), number_of_segments + 1)[1:-1]
        
        segment_indices = number_of_segments - 1 - np.where(segments[:, None] >= distribution[None, :], 1, 0).sum(0)
        
        if remove_outlier_above_segment:
            a = remove_outlier_above_segment[i]
            distribution = distribution[segment_indices <= a]
            segment_indices = segment_indices[segment_indices <= a]

        if remove_outlier_below_segment:
            b = remove_outlier_below_segment[i]
            distribution = distribution[segment_indices >= b - 1]
            segment_indices = segment_indices[segment_indices >= b - 1]
        segment_indices_list.append(segment_indices)

        values, counts = np.unique(segment_indices, return_counts=True)
        if np.max(counts) > max_counts:
            max_counts = np.max(counts)
        counts_filled = []
        j = 0
        for k in range(number_of_segments):
            if k in values:
                counts_filled.append(counts[j])
                j += 1
            else:
                counts_filled.append(0)
        counts_filled_list.append(counts_filled)

    for i in range(len(distributions)):    
        #print(f"counts filled {counts_filled}")
        variances = (max_plot_width / 2) * (counts_filled_list[i] / max_counts)
        #print(f"variances {variances}")
        jitter_unadjusted = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, len(distributions[i])) 
        jitter = np.take(variances, segment_indices_list[i]) * jitter_unadjusted

        # print(f"jitter {jitter}")
        ax.scatter(jitter + ticks[i], distributions[i], alpha=alpha)

    ax.set_xticks(ticks)
    ax.set_xticklabels(tick_labels)
    if vertical_limits:
        ax.set_ylim(bottom=vertical_limits[0], top=vertical_limits[1])
    if not grid:
        ax.grid(False)
    if y_label:
        ax.set_ylabel(y_label)
    if title:
        ax.set_title(title)
    plt.show()

That from the data in your toy example gives

The code is quite messy and duplicating the for loops is nor very elegant nor efficient: I hope at least the result is what you were looking for.
